# Extract specific keywords from a sentence using NLP python (I have dictionary of approx. 4 million keywords)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, text-extraction

I am learning NLP and have basic knowledge.

I have a CSV file which contains approx. million rows which has 4 important columns.

**Dataset(Dummy data, not the actual set):**

[image]

```
Sentence: BLA BLA ABC44, FUNNY CAT TEST COLOR BE SAFE, STAY HOME
Answer: Style_no: ABC44, Style_name: FUNNY CAT, Color_no: 200, Color_name: TEST COLOR
```

In the dataset each row is unique. In my example, 3 properties are there in the sentence, It is possible we may have 2 properties, in that case it should search and return all the columns.

I am trying to build this with Spacy, I am looking for guidance/algorithm/code.
Feel free to suggest me tutorial as well.

Comment: Just use simple string matching for this. Anything else looks like overkill.

Comment: @OliverMason it takes approx. 2-5 mins to search. I hope, That is why we need NLP there.

Comment: You don't need NLP here. Trust me.

Comment: You should use a trie-based approach. spaCy has rule-based matching but if you have 4M patterns it will be too slow. That said if you have 4M patterns I think you need to rethink your problem; unfortunately doing that requires more help than is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OliverMason and polm23
Ok, what do you suggest apart from NLP. How could i make it fast?

Comment: Create an index from the column values to the rows, and match the elements from that index in your text; then you can retrieve the required rows.